# Deploy ELK stack on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I am trying to set up ELK stack on AWS EC2 instance. I am new to this and i am following this tutorial I found online: https://avarjana.medium.com/setting-up-elk-stack-elastic-stack-on-aws-ec2-instance-fc2e1b006fe3.

But when I run `service elasticsearch start`, I get this error message:

`Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`

`See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xeu elasticsearch.service" for details.`

Any idea what is going on? Can't the ELK stack be deployed on AWS?

Comment: What is the output from the commands recommended?  They should show you what is going on.  ELK works fine on AWS.

Comment: Figured it out. It was an indentation issue in my ```elasticsearch.yml``` file.

Comment: Is it resolved ?

Comment: @sidharthvijayakumar yes, it is

Comment: You can post it in the answer as well if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like OP said this issue was caused due to bad indentation in elasticsearch.yml file.